# Is there any performance or memory issue when creating local variables to store data

Tags: dart

Say I've this statement:

```
final output = MyEnum.values[myPreferences.getIndex('some_key') ?? getDefaultIndex('some_key')];
```

I can store the value of those two expressions in a local variable like:

```
final savedIndex =  myPreferences.getIndex('some_key');
final defaultIndex = getDefaultIndex('some_key');
final output = MyEnum.values[savedIndex ?? defaultIndex];
```

Will this cause performance / memory issues if I do the same refactoring (create two additional local variables to make the code look more readable) on 1000s of my `output` type variables?

---

PS: Please don't advise on how I can get the default value in a better way from `SharedPreferences` and how I could reduce the above statement. I am just using the example to give an illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Most likely not*. I wouldn't worry about it.

Dart can be hard to optimize in some cases, but local variables is one thing compilers are *very* good at dealing with.
Unless your code allocates a gargantuan object, puts it into a local variable, uses it once and never needs it again, and then goes on to do a very long computation, I wouldn't worry about a local variable keeping the value alive. Even in that situation, the compiler will almost certainly still not keep the value alive after it's no longer needed (and if it does, it would probably do it even if you don't use a variable for your intermediate value), and I'd only start investigating if I'm actually seeing issues.

Don't worry, trust the compiler.

Comment: I could only trust couple of users for this post here on SO.